# Preview html markup of the documents edited in Sublime Text 3 in custom browser

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

(English is not my native language)

Hello. I want to preview quickly the html documents edited in Sublime Text 3. I found a plugin [View in browser](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser), but this plugin support only [Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser/wiki/Supported-Browsers). My browser is Pale Moon, the file of start is in the Windows folder `D:\Pale Moon\palemoon.exe`. May I quickly preview html documents in my browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pale Moon can be launched with a command-line argument telling it where to go:

```
"D:\Pale Moon\palemoon.exe" "stackoverflow.com"
```

This means that we can use a Sublime Text build system to open the current file in Pale Moon. Go to Tools > Build System > New Build System... and then enter this into new document:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "\"D:/Pale Moon/palemoon.exe\" \"$file\""
}
```

Save that into `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` (it'll probably default to this location)  as `Preview in Pale Moon.sublime-build`. Now, in your HTML document, go to Tools > Build System > Preview in Pale Moon.

Now, whenever you want to open Pale Moon to your current Sublime Text document, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.